# Disabling click on all elements inside DIV using jQuery 2.1.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I disable click on all elements inside DIV?

```
<div id=largerdiv>

<button id=haha>haha1</button>

<textarea > </textarea>

</div>
```

I want to disable click on both of the elements inside the div above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just set the disabled attribute on both elements:

```html
<textarea disabled></textarea>
<button disabled></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable all inputs..

```js
$("#discobal :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="discobal">
  <textarea>abc</textarea>
  <button>abc</button>
</form>
```

With divs:

```js
$("#discobal :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="discobal">
  <textarea>abc</textarea>
  <button>abc</button>
</div>
```

With a clickker:

```js
$("#repensteeltje").click(function() {
  $("#discobal :input").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="discobal">
  <textarea>abc</textarea>
  <button>abc</button>
</div>
<button id="repensteeltje">Disable all</button>
```

Comment: Well disapointed.. he ask for jquery and i give all the option and it's not good enough...